# Suggestions on managing social media accounts

Tags: social-media, social-networking

As a company we now have Facebook, LinkedIN, Twitter and now Google+, is there a way to easily manage all these accounts without having to log into them individually?

Things like posting content to each one is becoming a full time job in itself, is there a way to post once that in turn posts to all other accounts? I used to use http://ping.fm/ a long time ago, has there been any advancements in something similar to this?

With friend lists, news feeds etc etc for each one, I wish there was a way to manage them all in one place with a service/tool!

Comment: There are various tools that go between the first three. Google+ is rather new and there's no API yet. If I were you I'd wait a month or two until Google+ tools come along and then you can have a unified solution.

Comment: @paulmorriss Was just about to ask that, it seems as though any tools or software that currently handle the majority of social media networks will add Google+ eventually.

Comment: I asked practically the same thing here - http://superuser.com/questions/359942/multi-session-handling-web-browsers/. I'm not saying yours is a duplicate, just that the answers there may be of some value to you. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at something like [Seesmic](http://seesmic.com/) which allows you to manage all your social accounts in one place. I have also read a lot about [radion6](http://www.radian6.com/) although have no experience with that software. [Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) is another example.

Although I would say pushing all the same content out to each different network may not be the best approach, as if people follow you across networks it could be seen as filling up the feeds with duplicate information ( although I am aware a lot of people do this).

Comment: I just realised Tweetdeck also does the same, the name threw me a bit! Seesmic looks good though, although I'll have to wait for Google+.

Comment: I could not think of Tweekdeck at the time! but your right, it will come down to personal preference which one to use though.

Answer (score 1):

- [HelloTxt](http://hellotxt.com/) - more like ping.fm service
- [Atomkeep](http://www.atomkeep.com/) - attempts to solve social networks profiles synchronization problem :)

Answer (score 0):

At this moment (2013), (Hootsuite)[https://hootsuite.com/] could be a good answer. I used the pro version for long time.

But after several months I realized, as Matthew Brookes reasonably said, that every social network has its own *mood* and it's very unuseful to post the same content everywhere.

For example, I use FB to build a community. G+ exclusively for SEO reasons (in my country G+ is used very little). LinkedIn is good for B2B purposes so I don't think is a good idea to post spiritual quotes here. Twitter is good to assist customer.

In conclusion, you don't have to reach all the people in the world to increments leads. Being useful to your actual contacts is a good starting point.